# Cannot get samples to work with youtube-api; authorization problems

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to run sample: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py and am getting errors. That is, I'm unsure what to replace DEVELOPER_KEY with.

Since I'm guess I'm not using OAuth, I should have Public API, but am unsure how to proceed, since all I want to do is run from terminal this script and get some output.

I've tried creating Server Public API access with ip set to 0.0.0.0/32; but when trying to run this sample with API key I get the following error:

```
An HTTP error 403 occurred:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Ideally, my goal is to run a search query, get top few videos and print their view count.

EDIT:

I've opted out for using server API access with any key accepted. I fiddled with 0.0.0.0/32 because I misunderstood if I left the field blank any IP would be accepted. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [register your application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=fr).

**STEP 1.**

Creat a project. It's a large button you cannot miss him !

**STEP 2.**

Go in your project in the section APIs

Search on YouTube API use the version 3. You need to go down the page an enable `YouTube Data API v3`

Basically `YouTube Data API v3` is now to ON

**STEP 3.**

Go in the section `Credentials` and click :

```
Creat a new key
```

After that, you will have [several options](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys) :

> Two kinds of API keys are available in the Google Developers Console:
>
> Use a server key if your application is running on a server. Never
>   share this kind of API key outside your server code. For example,
>   never embed this key in a web page. To prevent quota theft, restrict
>   your key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source
>   IP addresses. 
> Use a browser key if your application is running on a
>   client, for example from JavaScript or any other client-side
>   web-browser context. To prevent your browser key from being used on
>   unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains that you
>   administer.

So after you have your API Key (wich is public)

[image]

Then use it in your code !